# Understanding Scaffolding in Rails Better

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scaffolding

I've read the rails guides but there are some things that when I actually do it myself I still do not understand.

For example, how come when I visit my show view on localhost I get an error? Scaffolding created a show action in my controller that is empty and a view but still get an error message.

Similar thing happens with index.

Isn't the purpose of scaffolding to help you with all this? I assumed if I made a few posts that the index action would take me to an index of all the posts but it doesn't instead the post/ itself lists them all. What is the logic behind scaffolding doing this?

EDIT::::

This is the error message that I get:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ExperimentsController#show
Couldn't find Experiment with id=index
```

This happens when I visit `http://localhost:3000/experiments/index`

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: How come i get an error when I visit my /show & /index after generating scaffold...

Comment: Post your code and the error which you getting.With that we cant help you!

Comment: Updated with my error code, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the routes incorrectly.
To visit the index page : you need url `http://localhost:3000/experiments`

When you specify url : `http://localhost:3000/experiments/index`, Rails would match it to the route of `show page`(as shown below): `/experiments/:id`

If you read the error carefully:

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ExperimentsController#show
Couldn't find Experiment with id=index`

Rails mapped the url to `show` action and is trying to find an experiment with `id=index` which obviously does not exist and you get an error.

Run `rake routes` on command prompt and you'll see the routes created for resource `experiment` as follows:

```
           /experiments             index      display a list of all experiments
GET        /experiments/new         new        return an HTML form for creating a new experiment
POST       /experiments             create     create a new experiment
GET        /experiments/:id         show       display a specific experiment
GET        /experiments/:id/edit    edit       returns an HTML form for editing an experiments
PATCH/PUT  /experiments/:id         update     update a specific experiment
DELETE     /experiments/:id         destroy    delete a specific experiment
```

You can access the specific routes with the paths shown above.
Replace `:id` with an existing `experiment` records `id` attribute value.

For eg:

To view an experiment with id `5`
Visit `http://localhost:3000/experiments/5`

**NOTE: I would highly recommend you to go through the [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) Guide and get a better idea of how Routing works.**

Answer (score 0):

For a simple scaffolding task and assuming you followed the [convention of naming](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#convention-over-configuration-in-active-record), you should never get any errors, but even if you got an error my guess it will be a simple typo or pending-migrations type of error (something a quick googling should resolve)

Scaffolds are meant to give a push and increase *Rapid Prototyping* of your app but won't do the hole job for you.

I remember being confused just like you some time ago and i too was looking at the wrong direction trying to figure out what **Scaffolding** do while i should have looked on **How Rails template system works** which is the next step after learning **[Rails MVC](http://www.codelearn.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial/mvc-in-rails)** basics.

Start from the guides, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#overview-how-the-pieces-fit-together and it will take some time to fully understand how rails works!